# Operations in find content page not working

Tags: 7

[image]
I am using Drupal 7 and I don't see any options listed down in the operations drop down in the find content page. The options are listed in content's tab, but when I move to files tab, the drop down is not shown.

Do you have the options to operate(delete, unpublish) files as we do to nodes? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: only content can be published or unpublished.

Comment: That's not a normal D7 content management screen though. Must be a contrib module.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try selecting some files before (tick checkbox)?
Some filters only appears when contents are selected (in the Media tab for example in my website)